# Finitely generated $K_0$ of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras. Let $A_0$ be a dense *-subalgebra of $A$, and let $B_0$ a dense *-subalgebra of $B$. Assume that $A_0$ is isomorphic to $B_0$.

Finally, assume that $K_0(A)$ is finitely generated. Must $K_0(B)$ also be finitely generated?

The isomorphism between $A_0$ and $B_0$ is an algebraic isomorphism between algebras over the field of complex numbers; it need not be a $*$-isomorphism.

Comment: If $A_0$ and $B_0$ are not necessarily isomorphic as $*$-algebras, then in what category *are* they assumed isomorphic?

Comment: How about the following. Take $A_0 = B_0 = {\bf C}G$ (the group algebra on the group $G$), and suppose that $G$ is not amenable. Then the maximum and minimum norms yield non-isomorphic C*-algebras $A$ and $B$ respectively.  I am not that familiar with the horde of results in this area, but there presumably are examples where one of them has merely ${\bf Z}$ as its $K_0$, and the other one has lots of  projection-equivalence classes, enough to guarantee non-finite generation.

Comment: Of course what I meant by *maximum and minimum norms* were the full and regular representation norms, but that occurred to me just more than five minutes after ...

Comment: It's certainly your right to rollback edits to the question, but why insist on $C*$ in place of $C^*$, and why the '---'s?

Comment: When a dense subalgebra is invariant under analytic functional calculus, its K-theory is isomorphic to that of the ambient algebra, so I suggest you check whether that property holds on the examples you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

No. To obtain a counterexample, you just need a C*-algebra $A$ with finitely generated K-theory and a quotient $A/I$ of $A$ which does not have finitely generated K-theory and the quotient algebraically preserves some dense subalgebra of $A$. Here is the easiest example of this situation that I could think of.

Let $A=C[0,1]$ and let $B$ be the C*-algebra of convergent sequences. Then $K_0(A)$ is finitely generated while $K_0(B)$ is not. Define the surjective map $\pi:A\rightarrow B$ by $\pi(f)(n)=f(1/n).$  Let $A_0\subseteq A$ be polynomials and let $B_0=\pi(A_0),$ which is a dense subalgebra of $B.$  Since $\pi$ is injective on $A_0$ it defines a *-isomorphism between $A_0$ and $B_0.$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $K_0(A) \neq K_0(B)$ in general. Take for example, what Handelman pointed out, the full and reduced group $C^*$-algebras of a group $G$ which is not $K$-amenable, i.e. $K_0(C^* G) \neq K_0(C^*_r G)$.

It is fair to assume that we may find an example where $K_0(A)=0$ but $K_0(B) \neq 0$.

If you accept this, then you immediately have a counterexample.

Take $a_0:=\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} A_0$ with two distinct closures
$a:=\bigoplus A$ ($C^*$-direct inifinite sum of $A$) and similarly $b:=\bigoplus B$.

Then $a_0$ is dense in $a$ and $b$.

But $K_0(a) = \bigoplus K_0(A) =0$ is finitely generated, and $K_0(b)= \bigoplus K_0(B)$ is infinitely generated.

That is why I am confident that your question is answered to the negative.